# Adding background color to input boxes with jquery currently only TD is highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have TD rows in my table highlighing, but I need the background of my input boxes to highlight as well.
Shouldn't I be able to "chain" the input into the existing function?

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/d3L0djb6/

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
//console.log('t');
$('[id*=dgKey] td').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#EAD575');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '#EAD575');
});
$('[id*=dgKey] td').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '');
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
<table id="dgKeyWhatever">
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:Large;">D</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;width:150px;">&nbsp;Sharp, John</td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$TotalOT" type="text" value="219.0" size="6" readonly="readonly" id="dgKey_TotalOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$PendingOT" type="text" value="12.0" size="6" id="dgKey_PendingOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$ScheduledOT" type="text" value="183.0" size="6" id="dgKey_ScheduledOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$TurnedDownOT" type="text" value="24.0" size="6" id="dgKey_TurnedDownOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$FudgeFactor" type="text" value="0.0" size="6" id="dgKey_FudgeFactor_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$HomeNum" type="text" value="623-561-8099" size="12" id="dgKey_HomeNum_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="dgKey$ctl02$CellNum" type="text" value="602-619-2933" size="12" id="dgKey_CellNum_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;">&nbsp;JLSHARP</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;">&nbsp;SUPERVISOR</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why are you doing mouseover css using js?

Comment: So don't. There are css selectors for that (`:hover`)

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS rule:

```
#dgKeyWhatever input {
    background: inherit;
    border-width: 0; // add this to make it more beautiful
}
```

This will make sure that your input elements inherit the background color from its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answers, you can simplify your jQuery code by toggling a class that contains the background color you've chosen:

```
$('tr').has('input[id^="dgKey"]').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('foo');
});
```

This event will only bind to `tr` elements that have child `input` elements with id codes beginning with `dgKey`. On the hover it event, it will toggle the class foo, (add if doesn't exist, remove if does.) You're css classes would then look like the following:

```
/*from the accepted answer */
tr:hover input[id^="dgKey"] {
    background: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*the class containing the bg color to toggle */
.foo{
    background-color: #EAD575;
}
```

Example:

```js
$('tr').has('input[id^="dgKey"]').hover(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
tr:hover input[id^="dgKey"] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.foo{
    background-color: #EAD575;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dgKeyWhatever">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:Large;">D</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;width:150px;">&nbsp;Sharp, John</td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$TotalOT" type="text" value="219.0" size="6" readonly="readonly" id="dgKey_TotalOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$PendingOT" type="text" value="12.0" size="6" id="dgKey_PendingOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$ScheduledOT" type="text" value="183.0" size="6" id="dgKey_ScheduledOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$TurnedDownOT" type="text" value="24.0" size="6" id="dgKey_TurnedDownOT_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$FudgeFactor" type="text" value="0.0" size="6" id="dgKey_FudgeFactor_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:right" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$HomeNum" type="text" value="623-561-8099" size="12" id="dgKey_HomeNum_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="dgKey$ctl02$CellNum" type="text" value="602-619-2933" size="12" id="dgKey_CellNum_0" style="font-size:18pt;text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;">&nbsp;JLSHARP</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:Large;">&nbsp;SUPERVISOR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```